# Detecting an inserted cell and then having it becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For my custom cell, for a simple example, I have just one `UITextField`, is there a way to have the cell `becomeFirstResponder` that just got inserted by `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` ?

I need a way to detect this so it becomes first responder AFTER it has been inserted and **when it's insertion animation ends**.

Any ideas or even close to it?

Thanks

Comment: Will you always have one row inserted? or is it possible to have multiple row inserted? then which one would you want as the first responder?

Comment: Is always one row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this??

```
- (void) insertRows
{
    .
    .
    .

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    NSIndexPath p = [indexPaths lastObject];

    MyCustomCell *cell = [cellForRowAtIndexPath:p];
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: How would this work if I'm also using cell dequeing at cellForRowAtIndexPath?  After doing insertRowsAtIndexPaths, cellForRowAtIndexPath would be called.  Is there a call back I can use to detect when the animation ends.

Comment: Also, why do you need the [tableView beginUpdates]/endUpdates?  The animation works fine without it.

Comment: if it works without begin/endUpdates then thats fine..  but you will have to scroll the tableView to
recently inserted row so it is visible 

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:p atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

MyCustomCell *cell = [cellForRowAtIndexPath:p];
[cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];